# What is the value in the Accumulator?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 68hc08, 68hc

This is a practice question for an exam on Microcontrollers involving Assembly Language, it asks to find the content in the accumulator after the final line has been executed. I can't understand how the answer is $5C if anyone has any knowledge of Assembly please help me!

```
     START: LDA   #$11  ; load accumulator

            STA   $2123 ; store accumulator to a memory address

            CLRA

            LDA   #$67     ; load accumulator

            LDHX  #$2120    ; load index register

            SUB   $03, X   ;subtract accumulator using index register

            ADD   #$06      ; add accumulator
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
START: LDA   #$11  ; load accumulator
 - A=$11
       STA   $2123 ; store accumulator to a memory address
 - memory[$2123] = $11
       CLRA
 - A=$00 (redundant, as next instruction will load A again)
       LDA   #$67     ; load accumulator
 - A=$67
       LDHX  #$2120    ; load index register
 - H:X=$2120
       SUB   $03, X   ;subtract accumulator using index register
 - this is addressing mode "Indexed, 8-Bit Offset" (indexed by H:X)
 - target memory address is calculated as H:X+$03 = $2123
 - finally subtraction is done on A: A=A-memory[$2123] ($67-$11=$56)
       ADD   #$06      ; add accumulator
 - A=A+$06 ($56+$06=$5C)
```

Pay attention to `#$` vs `$` (immediate hexadecimal value vs memory address/offset hexadecimal value) and overall to the syntax of your assembler (I'm actually mostly guessing which CPU and assembler exactly you are using, seems like Freescale HCS08, but you should know better and I never did code for similar one), as each assembler can have subtle (different) details how to write certain machine instructions, and every CPU has different instruction set (which instructions are available and how you can resolve certain programming problems with them effectively).

So you should know the syntax good enough to correctly asses which instruction is produced by particular line, and then you can check the instruction set manual, what exactly that instruction (and its variant) does. It also helps a lot to practice with debugger, actually writing some small tasks and single-stepping in debugger over each instruction, comparing the actual results with your assumptions.

Comment: Many Thanks for your advice, you guessed the MCU spot on and as you can probably tell I am very new to programming and understanding the basics.

Comment: @EvilMonkey or Ped7g: one of you should tag this question with the right architecture.  `[assembly]` on its own isn't useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes the 68hcXX had only tags 11 and 12, so I added the 08 tag too... just realizing by reading wikipedia, that there's also 05, and that Freescale Semiconductors actually *is* former Motorola, I had that "M" word on the tip of tongue all the time, but couldn't exactly see it anywhere in the docs... That's what happens, when you live happily under the rock.. :D

Comment: @Ped7g: time for a `68hc` generic tag?  Or are they separate ISAs?

Comment: @PeterCordes quite different in my badly-informed opinion... 05 and 08 seems to be more related to 6800/M6502 (although the 68hc08 seems to be designed somewhat apart from 6800), while 11 and 12 are more 68000 relatives (having different ISA too). The 12 having 16b data bus internally is like completely different beast, etc... I'm very new to Motorola/Freescale CPUs, I was always the Zilog + Intel guy, so I'm leaving that discussion to more informed ones, but it seems to me you need to specify the precise model when dealing with asm source (even hc08 has extended "hcs08" variant).

Comment: I don't think creating a `68hc` tag would be a bad idea. Basically all of these are offspring of 6800. First there was 68HC05, then 68HC08, then 68HC11. Then some bastard experiments that never because mainstream: 68HC12 and 68HC16. The mainstream cores still in production are HCS08 (8 bit) and HCS12 (16 bit). All of these have very similar assembler, but with some small differences here and there. Rather than having a niche tag for every architecture, we could merge them into one.

Comment: @Lundin ok.. I'm afraid from the point of view of answering question the specific chip is essential, so I hope the general tag will not discourage question authors from specifying their target precisely, but otherwise I don't see any more, why having general tag would hurt. I did add it, but I have low rep, so it's awaiting reviews. Plus I put there some first version of description, feel free anyone to improve on it, I'm actually not even sure what is best content for the tag itself and how to write it.